# Sort timestamps by date in Java

Tags: android, timestamp

I have class `Event` that has bunch of different variables like **name**, **description**, **start time** and **end time**, and then I have `Day` class that has variable date and `ArrayList` of these `Events`. Now I want to have ArrayList of `Days`, and every `Day` should contain `Events` that are on the same day. By default I get list of events and I need to create days based on this list. All times are in **int** `unix timestamp` format.

Example to clarify what I am after for:

```
Day 25.11
Event1
Event2
Event3

Day 26.11
Event1

Day 27.11
Event1
Event2
Event3
Event4
```

there is the code I tried without working results:

```
private void getObjects(String url) throws JSONException, Exception {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(new NetTask().execute(url).get());
        JSONArray job1 = jsonObject.getJSONArray("events");
        ArrayList<Event> events = new ArrayList<Event>();
        Calendar calPrev = Calendar.getInstance();
        boolean first = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < job1.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject myEventArray = job1.getJSONObject(i);
            int start = myEventArray.getInt("start");
            int end = myEventArray.getInt("end");
            String name = myEventArray.getString("name");
            String description = myEventArray.getString("description");

            if(first){
                calPrev.setTimeInMillis(start*1000L);
                events.add(new Event(start,end,name,description));
                first = false;
            }else{
                Calendar calCur = Calendar.getInstance();
                calCur.setTimeInMillis(start*1000L);

                if(calPrev.get(Calendar.YEAR) == calCur.get(Calendar.YEAR) && calPrev.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) == calCur.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)){
                    events.add(new Event(start,end,name,description));
                }else{
                    days.add(new Day(323,events)); // HERE I CREATE NEW DAY AND ADD IT TO ARRAY
                    events.clear();
                    events.add(new Event(start,end,name,description));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: New readers to this question should throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. Use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) in order to use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It is so much nicer to work with. Find the event date from `Instant.ofEpochSecond(start).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to get unique days and then add events for every day into hash map `private HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<YourModel>> eventInfo = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<YourModel>>();`:

```
private List<String> getUniqueDays(List<YourModel> list)
{
    Set<String> res = new LinkedHashSet<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    {
        if (list.get(i).getDay().length() > 0)
            res.add(list.get(i).getDay());
    }

    List<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>(res);
    Collections.sort(temp, dateComparator);
    return temp;
}

Comparator<String> dateComparator = new Comparator<String>()
{
    @Override
    public int compare(String lhs, String rhs)
    {
        try
        {
            DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy h:mm:ss a");
            return format.parse(lhs).compareTo(format.parse(rhs));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I dont quite understand what you are after with this

Comment: for example what do you mean by "YourModel"?

Comment: YourModel is class where you implement getters and setters for day, description, name, etc.

Comment: Example: `public class YourModel 
{
 private int id = -1;
 private String title = "";
 private String day = "";
 private String description = "";

 public int getId()
 {
  return id;
 }

 public void setId(int id)
 {
  this.id = id;
 }
 
 // Other getters and setters
}`

Comment: Ok now I understand what this code is doing. It only sorts all the Events I have, but I still need to be able to create "Days" out of this list

Comment: It not only sorts, it also get list of unique days from your list.

Comment: Could you please comment your code, im pretty new to lista and comparators, thanks.

Comment: In your code you have `ArrayList<Event> events = new ArrayList<Event>(); // list of all events`, then with the help of **getUniqueDays** method you can get list of unique days like in your question i.e. `ArrayList<Event> uniqueEvents = getUniqueDays(events);` then I use comparator to sort list of unique days. In my case I sort days by Date type, maybe in you case better to use sort by long value or something else. In general sort is unnecessary.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can easily do that.

Step 1: Define a Tree-Map

```
Map<Date, String> mainUsers = new TreeMap<>();
```

Step 2: convert time-stamp into date like this

```
Long tStamp = snapshot1.child("lastMsgTime").getValue(Long.class); // timestamps
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a");
Date date = new Date(tStamp);
```

Step 3: add date as key like this

```
mainUsers.put(date, snapshot1.getKey().substring(28, 56));
```

TreeMap automatically arrange items in ascending order but if you want in descending order then, you can easily do that;

Step 4: first store map keys into a array of strings or whatever suitable datatype then reverse list users (in my case)

```
Collections.reverse(users);
```

Comment: Please don’t suggest using `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`. Those classes are troublesome and long outdated. When this question was asked in 2012, they were what we had (apart from Joda-Time), but sine Java 8 there is no reason whatsoever to use them in new code. Use `LocalDateTime`, `LocalDate` nad `DateTimeFormatter` from [java.time, the modern java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html). Also your format pattern string is wrong and you are not obtaining the result requested in the question.

Comment: I think you are right but this actually worked for me, and that format also worked for me in my problem scenario if you feel this is incomplete then please repost your answer. Thanks for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: I am not writing an answer, but I put a comment under the question. And sorry, I was wrong, your format pattern is (probably) correct, but even though your code worked, it did not work for the problem asked about in the question.